# JSON returning Undefined with Javascript Parse

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am currently working on a project where using Javascript and JSON Objects I am trying to populate data in a popup modal. How the process works is, the user clicks the title of a feedback issue and using the id of the feedback issue data is pulled from the database and inserted into a JSON Object. The only problem is that the modal is returning with "Undefined" The first script is my showTicket function which is called using onclick.

```
function showTicket(id) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("issueHeader").innerHTML = myObj.title;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "./applet/ajax.fetchIssue.php?issueID="+id, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        jQuery('#issueModal').modal('show');
    }
```

The next script is how I am calling the data using `ajax.fetchIssue.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['issueID'])) {
    $modalQuery = dbQuery("SELECT * FROM `feedback` WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['issueID'] . "'");
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($modalQuery)) {
        echo '[{';
        echo '"title":"' . $data['subject'] . '", ';
        echo '"body":"' . $data['body'] . '", ';
        echo '"date":"' . $data['submission_date'] . '", ';
        echo '"category":"' . $data['feedback_category'] . '"';
        echo '}]';
    }
}
```

Now my JSON Object

```
[{"title":"Testing", "body":"Testing Feedback System...", "date":"2020-04-20", "category":"other"}]
```

I have looked at other threads and they don't seem to help me narrow down what my issue could be. Any and all feedback is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to debug your javascript part with console.logs and then find out what is being printed on console for `this.responseText ` and `myObj`. Btw your json is of type array. so use myObj[0].title

Comment: Please take precautions against MySQL injection. Sanitize and validate external input like $_GET values before inserting them in your queries. Or better yet, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements instead.

Comment: Well, the JSON here looks valid. Object inside 1 element array. Should parse. Test the `responseText` whether it's really a clean text and does not contain hidden BOM bytes. Convert the response to binary array and check whether the bytes are pure ASCII or something else. Then, for gods sake - do not build strings with SQL queries and JSON. Use appropriate tools / libs for that. The query part is a major SQL injection vulnerability, making JSON "by hand" can produce bugs later on. For DB best use ORM. Safer, faster, easier.

Comment: Is it possible that the database resultset values contain characters like single quotes? This could mess up the validity of the json syntax. Perhaps consider using json_encode for formatting the $data array.

Comment: @Harry - _"For DB best use ORM. Safer, faster, easier"_  - How would an ORM be faster than a plain query using mysqli or pdo directly? ORM's are good in _some_ situations, but can also be overkill (performance wise and added code complexity) in many other.

Comment: Well, computers are way faster than humans. Faster to design. In code-first approach you just make your models (you would do them anyway) - the rest is done by ORM. Well, you must also configure database, but you don't even design tables. There should be more minimalistic tutorials for that out there ;) The performance hit is negligible, unless of course you're doing something performance critical that must be fully optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composing json via `echo` is not very convenient) It may be easier to use `json_encode` via `array`.
Perhaps this will solve your problem.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    if (isset($_GET['issueID'])) {
        $array = array();
        $modalQuery = dbQuery("SELECT * FROM `feedback` WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['issueID'] . "'");
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($modalQuery)) {
            $array[] = array('title' => $data['subject'], 'body' => $data['body'], 'date' => $data['submission_date'], 'category' => $data['feedback_category']);
        }
        echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
?>
```

JS:

```
function showTicket(id) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "./applet/ajax.fetchIssue.php?issueID="+id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("issueHeader").innerHTML = myObj[0].title;
        }
    };
    jQuery('#issueModal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: This will also print undefined there seems to be issue at `document.getElementById("issueHeader").innerHTML = myObj.title;` it should be something like `document.getElementById("issueHeader").innerHTML = myObj[0].title;`

Answer (score 2):

[image: Check Browser console]

So from the screenshot you can see that your `myObj.title` will actually be undefined. As `myObj` is of type array. So you should better iterate over `myObj` and if only single object is expected then use simple JSON object and not array.